# MySQL: count appearance of sequences

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have table with:

| id | mode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | A |
| 6 | A |
| 7 | B |
| 8 | B |
| 9 | C |
| 10 | C |
| 11 | C |
| 12 | B |
| 13 | A |
| 14 | A |
| 15 | A |
| 16 | B |
| 17 | C |
| 18 | B |
| 19 | C |
| 20 | B |
| 21 | B |

i would like to count following sequences:

"start": xA -> xB -> xC

"stop": xC -> xB ->xA

so that final result for this table would be:

START = 2 (ID: 3-11, 13-17)

STOP = 1 (ID: 9-15)

Point is that i need to count only right mode changes, no matter how many times mode is recorded.

Can anybody help? (tnx!)

Comment: Collapse (remove row if `mode=LAG(mode)`) then test LEAD and LAG for a row with `mode='B'`.

Comment: @Akina tnx, i'll try.

Comment: I think the reason for the downvote is how you ask the question.. with that "Table"

Answer (score 0):

ok, i got this solved with:

```
select 
sum(case when prev= "A" and nxt="C"  then 1 else 0 end) as start,
sum(case when prev= "C" and nxt="A"  then 1 else 0 end) as stop
from (
select id, prev, mode, nxt
    from (
        select 
        id,
        LAG(mode)OVER (
            partition by 1
            order by id
            ) prev,
        mode, 
        LEAD(mode)OVER (
            partition by 1
            order by id
            )  nxt
        from prva
        order by id
    ) sub
    where mode <> nxt and mode="B"
) data
```